# performing calculation by calling values with .$ and .[ ]

Tags: r, tidyverse

This is purely a conceptual question, but how could I refer to the elements of my vector c(2,3) in a calculation using .$ or .[]?

```
library(tidyverse)

c(2, 3) %>% 
  .[1] * .[2]
```

This code works fine but requires a temporary object (v) to be created:

```
v <- c(2,3)
v[1] * v[2]
```

And I'd like to know how to perform the calculation in the tidyverse without creating the temporary object v.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to place the braces to avoid operator precedence

```
c(2, 3) %>%
        {.[1] * .[2]}
#[1] 6
```

Also, we could use `map2` to multiply corresponding elements (`tidyverse`)

```
map2_dbl(2, 3, `*`)
#[1] 6

map2_dbl(2:5, 6:9, `*`)
#[1] 12 21 32 45
```

Or with `reduce`

```
c(2, 3) %>% 
    reduce(`*`)
#[1] 6

list(2:5, 6:9) %>% 
           reduce(`*`)
#[1] 12 21 32 45
```

Comment: Great answer! Do you know why `\`*\`(1, 2)` works, but `1:2 %>% \`*\`{.[1], .[2]}` doesn't.

Comment: You'd need `1:2 %>% {` ``*`` `(.[1], .[2])}`, since `*` is a function and a function always needs `(`. The braces should be all around the function call.

Comment: @akrun, This is a really great answer. Thank you so much!